# Best practice for passing variable outside of the function

Tags: php, git

I'm using [gif-endec](https://github.com/stil/gif-endec) to manage my gif images. And I want to get the duration of each frame of the gif. Currently I'm using the scripts below :

```
$gifStream = new FileStream("myfile.gif");
$gifDecoder = new Decoder($gifStream);
Global $gifDurations;

$gifDecoder->decode(function (FrameDecodedEvent $event) {
  global $gifDurations;
  $gifDurations[] = $event->decodedFrame->getDuration();
});
```

The scripts works fine and the output is :

```
array(3) { [0]=> int(200) [1]=> int(200) [2]=> int(200) }
```

But I would like to know is there a better way to get the same result? I tried to use `return`, but it can't get the result. Or I just didn't do it in a proper way...

Please let me know if there is a better solution...

P.S. I tried to use [GifFrameExtractor](https://github.com/Sybio/GifFrameExtractor). It is simple to use, but it can't get the correct duration time.

Comment: Did you mean to tag `git`?

Comment: use `use (&$a)` drop global idea.

Comment: a `use`'less example: https://3v4l.org/DhZLg

Comment: @evolutionxbox Oh..yes. Sorry for the wrong tag.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone thank you. I will try for this

Comment: (You might want to change the tag so more relevant people can see the question)

Comment: I fail to see why you tagged, `git`. From what I see, it is a callback function, so a return will not work. Unwanted callbacks do mess up :( . you can try `wait` in php